# Electrical device for testing continuity of long home-run wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, testing

Does anyone know the name or have a link to an electrical testing device for verifying home-runs to electrical box?

Comment: A multi meter and a cheater death plug?

Comment: An old fashioned light-bulb or resistance heater obviate the need(?) for a  "death plug" by which I assume you mean a short-circuited plug. Check its resistance at its plug, plug it in, check its resistance + the wire resistance at the electrical box.

Comment: What about this?

http://a.co/4sgWv2A

Comment: True lion, did you post you have a toner? On another question? The toners I have have a continuity function where the light illuminates with continuity.

Comment: No. My post is about the best device to use for testing contunity on a long run of home-run 12-2 wire. Ex. I ran 5 home-runs to the main breaker box in garage, i want to verify and label each after testing that they all run to the correct rooms.

I found this device:
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000LYTTRK/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_ep_dp_6TEWybWN0JF0J

It's the Extech Instruments CT20 Remote and Local Continuity Tester

Comment: Having had rewired my entire house and replacing the service panel, I believe you need to clarify your question. Are you merely testing for continuity from receptacle, light socket, etc. to the panel? Are you trying to determine if a receptacle, light socket, etc. is the only device on the branch (circuit)? Whatever you're doing please make sure that the power to the service panel is dead; depending on its age some have a master breaker at the top. Many continuity devices will fry if connected to a live branch.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to label or find a wire, the typical way is to use a wire tracer. One end is a tone generator, the other end is a detector that can hear those tones.

You can get low-voltage ones, which can be used for (unpowered) electrical cables, ethernet/phone and cable:

[image]

You can also get specialty live-voltage tracers, many of which can be used if the circuit is powered:

[image]

---

If you're actually trying to get continuity (and get an ohms value) one way is to use a standard multimeter with a long extension cord. This only works if the circuit is unpowered (otherwise you risk blowing up your meter and/or electrocuting yourself). Plug in the extension cord at one end, and bring the other end to the source (eg, near the panel), then you can use one of the multimeter probes on the extension cord and the other on the wire you're testing.

Comment: I think this is what @Ed Beal was referring to :). Ed what brand (got a link) is yours? Thanks for explaining @ gregmac. Is this a good one?

IT IS a wire toner (wire tracer) that I need because I need to identify and label my 12-2 non-energized wires from my rooms back to my electrical box in garage. Not really about continuity.

Will this offer the functionality I am looking for?
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Sperry-Lan-WireTracker-Tone-and-Probe-Wire-Tracer-ET64220/202520187

Comment: @true.lion Yes, a tracer will give you that functionality. We don't do product recommendations here so I'd suggest just checking out some reviews of whichever one(s) you're considering.